# jQuery trigger double on a button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to trigger a double click on a button when the dropdown changes. Single click works for me but I want double click.

```js
$('#fruitIds').change(function() {
  $("#btn-search").dblclick();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="fruits" id="fruitIds" style="width: 140px;">
  <option selected="selected" value="">Days</option>
  <option value="5">5 Days</option>
  <option value="10">10 Days</option>
  <option value="15">15 Days</option>
  <option value="20">20 Days</option>
  <option value="25">25 Days</option>
</select>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn1" id="btn-search">Apply Filter</button>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why don't use just put the filter application code inside the `change` event handler? Also, if a single click works then why do you need a double click?

Comment: It will be a long explanation but I will just go for the single click for now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According jQuery:s documentation **dblClick** is deprecated and should be replaced with **trigger**.

Does this work for you:

```
$('#fruitIds').change(function() {
  $("#btn-search").trigger( "dblclick" );
});
```

Comment: Just note you could also just fire a click event twice

Comment: Does that work? Or is it considered two separate clicks?

Comment: I want to fire the click event twice on the dropdown change

Comment: @ThomasFrank a user separate-clicking a button twice would be the same thing

Comment: That depends on the timing between the clicks?

Comment: @ThomasFrank true so that would be 1 ms

Comment: I have actually done this before when I was a newbie at JS and didn’t know there was a “dblclick” event. It think it would work fine

Comment: Interesting - according to the other answer .dblClick is working fine... (I do recommend that you take the documentaton seriously and replace it with trigger to future-proof it though - when something i deprecated is often flagged for removal in future versions.)

Comment: @ThomasFrank lol yeah you have to pay attention to deprecation warnings… or one day you’ll wonder why your code is completely failing 

Comment: @ParkingMaster - is 1 ms always the limit? I would imaging that it is OS/OS-settings dependent but I could be wrong.

Comment: I think the timing depends on performance but 1ms is the lowest possible amount of delay

Answer (score 1):

Check Your Jquery version jquery 3.6.4 version perfectly working.
Example

```
$("element").dblclick(function(){
     $(this).fadeOut();
  });


$("element1").click(function(){
    $("element2").dblclick();
  });
```